# background-size: initial not working in IE10 and under

Tags: html, css, angular

Hi I have the following CSS class and dom element

```
<button [ngClass]="{ 'filter-icon-open': open, 'filter-icon-close': !open }">
</button>
```

**css**

```
.open-filter {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    button {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: initial;
    }
    button:hover {
        background-image: url("./../../../../assets/images/ico_filter_over.png");
        background-color: $dbsred;
        border: none;
    }
    button:focus {
        outline:none;
    }
}

.filter-icon-open {
    background-image: url("./../../../../assets/images/ico_filter_over.png");
    background-color: red;
}

.filter-icon-close {
    background-image: url("./../../../../assets/images/ico_filter.png");
    border: solid #B3B3B3 1px;
}
```

It's working perfectly for chrome. But for IE the icon is big. How to solve this. newbie to CSS. can someone help. Thanks in advance.

Tried:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./../../../../assets/images/ico_filter.png', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./../../../../assets/images/ico_filter.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

but i see this part been commented out in chrome and it didnt worked as well.

Comment: the problem is with the `filter-icon-close`. The image is bigger than the other one

Comment: Which IE version or do you mean edge? background-size is not supported in IE10 and below.

Comment: yeah its not supporting. Thats the issue

Comment: So which IE version are you referring to? You didnt't answer the question.

Comment: Sorry its IE10, but i may have users above that version

Answer (score 2):

`initial` is not supported on IE. For IE the permitted values for background-size 
 as per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127316(v=vs.85).aspx) are :

```
background-size: [ <length> | <percentage> | auto ] {1,2} | cover | contain [ , [ <length> | <percentage> | auto ] {1,2} | cover | contain ]*
```

Additionally, `initial` just sets the property to the default value of the property and for `background-size` the default value is `auto`. So you can use that directly or use any of the above values.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that the open and close images are different sizes, You can use CSS to resize the images in the browser:

```
.filter-icon-open {
    background-image: url("./../../../../assets/images/ico_filter_over.png");
    background-color: red;
    height : 100px;
    width : 100px;
}

.filter-icon-close {
    background-image: url("./../../../../assets/images/ico_filter.png");
    border: solid #B3B3B3 1px;
    height : 100px;
    width : 100px;
}
```

This will force both the open and close image to be the same size, however, I personally recommend against that approach, since it could cause skewing or pixelation of the image.

A better solution is to resize the images using an image editing tool of your choice, such as Photoshop.

Comment: I have height and width set in the button. So this height and width wont get valid.